# How to have yank visually flash the pasted text

Tags: yank

I'd like to be able to paste text into a buffer and have emacs give a visual confirmation by flashing the region (highlighting and unhighlighting) the text that was pasted in the buffer. Is there an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways that I know of:

- [`volatile-highlights`](https://github.com/k-talo/volatile-highlights.el): an external package which gives you visual feedback for many operations, including yanking.
- `pulse`: a built-in library you can leverage to achieve what you want. You can advice `yank` to use `pulse-momentary-highlight-region`, for instance.
- [`goggles`](https://github.com/minad/goggles): another external package. This one uses `pulse` to do the highlighting. From its README:

> This library is the holy counterpart of `evil-goggles`. Another
> comparable library is `volatile-highlights`, which does not use pulse.
> By setting `goggle-pulse` to `nil`, the `goggles-mode` behaves similarly to
> the `volatile-highlights-mode`.

Comment: thanks for that. volatile highlights is a great package.